# Exception while reading spring configuration xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am getting below exception while loading my spring application.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [Spring-Module.xml] is
>   invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
>
> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.

config xml -

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="Spring-Datasource.xml"/>
    <import resource="Spring-Report.xml"/>

    <!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:email.properties" /> -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:D:\\jithin\\email.properties" />

    <bean id="mailUtil" class="com.bmlr.report.util.MailUtil">
        <property name="host" value ="${mail.host.url}"/>
        <property name="port" value ="${mail.port.num}"/>
        <property name="auth" value ="${mail.auth.val}"/>
        <property name="user" value ="${mail.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value ="${mail.password}"/>
        <property name="fromaddr" value ="${mail.fromList}"/>
        <property name="toaddr"   value ="${mail.toList}"/>
        <property name="ccaddr"   value ="${mail.ccList}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="excelUtil" class="com.bmlr.report.util.ExcelUtil">
        <property name="inputPath" value ="${excel.reportinputPath}"/>
        <property name="outputPath" value ="${excel.reportoutputPath}"/>
        <property name="reportName" value ="${excel.inputReportName}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Stack trace -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [Spring-Module.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.bmlr.report.cb.ReportCB.processreport(ReportCB.java:25)
    at com.bmlr.report.App.main(App.java:27)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Share the project url please

Comment: This was due to issue in vpn connection. I have disconnected the vpn and now the program is working fine!!! :)

Comment: yes - that was what I was thinking. That you don't see the schema file. If you want to avoid that kind of thing you can put the schema file locally instead.

Comment: @froderik okay..